# Failed to install ubuntu through unetbootin- now can't boot from USB

Tags: 14.04, boot, usb

I tried to install Ubuntu on my Windows PC with unetbootin. The installation failed during partitioning. I restarted my computer and now cant access my old Windows (which is ok, I dont need it) or ubuntu. The computer just stays on the page that comes right after the bios. I've checked the related questions and the thing is, I've already installed Windows from USB on this computer, that's not my problem. I selected USB to be the priority in the bios, in a separate boot menu I select the USB as the priority boot device and nothing's changing. I've tried 3 USB's, two OS's, two USB to Boot programs and when I plug in the USB it's as if nothing's there (even though the name of the USB appears on the screen after the bios, so clearly the computer recognizes the USB). I'm at a loss and I'm going crazy, is there something I can do here?

Answer (score 0):

Reset BIOS settings to default, and try hitting f7/f12 and selecting USB manually, also next step would be if your laptop has a disk drive to try booting from any LiveCD like gparted-live.iso and then wipe HD.